# Utilization of heap space

Tags: jboss

Is heap memory dynamically utilized or it is reserved?

Suppose, I've a JVM (possibly JBoss) and I allocated 2 GB max heap size. Does that mean, when the JBoss server is running, this 2 GB memory is completely reserved by that process and not be shared with other process even though 2GB of jboss process is not utilized at all?

Could someone please clarify my doubt?

Answer (score 0):

It is dynamically allocated. The "minimum" setting is what controls what is reserved.